# How to use touch screen for movement instead of keyboard narrow keys

Tags: unity, 2d, android, unityscript

I wrote this code and run the game on my desktop, now I need to build this game for android and I need to change to touch to move the player, what it should be changed in the following code and what is the necessary steps to build my desktop 2D game to be run on android device, the following is the player code:

```
#pragma strict

var speed : int = 5;

function Start () {
}

function Update () {

  if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") >0){

    if(collided_with != null) {
      if(collided_with.tag== "Right") {
        //collided_with=null;
        return;
      }
    }
    transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*speed*Time.deltaTime,0,0));
  }

  if(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") <0) {
    if(collided_with != null) {
      if(collided_with.tag == "Left"){  
        // collided_with=null;
        return;
      }
    }  
    transform.Translate(Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal")*speed*Time.deltaTime,0,0));
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you try that did not work?

Comment: could you edit my code / question

Comment: I need to change to touch

Comment: no because when i build my game for android, the player did not move upon the movement of my fingure on touch screen

Answer (score 2):

Touchscreen devices do not have keys, so you need to think about another input method.

A quick and dirty solution to adapt a game designed to be controlled with directional keys to a touch device is to use a "virtual keypad". Use [the Unity UI system](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html) to create four buttons on the screen the player can tab on, and bind each to an appropriate function which moves the player-character. But this is an obvious crutch which shows that the game was clearly not designed with touchscreens in mind.

A better solution would be to reconceptualize the game input to tilting the device, touch and/or swipe gestures, but there is no canonical solution for this because different kinds of input actions are suitable for different kinds of games and the choices you make here greatly affect the player experience.

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a separate function for touch screen devices. Here' the code. Note that functions MoveLeft() and MoveRight() are exaggerated, so you need to replace them with your own.

C# Code:

```
function Update () 
{            
     for (int i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) 
     {
         Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

         if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
         {
            if (touch.position.x > (Screen.width/2)) 
            {
                MoveRight(); //moves player right
            }

            if (touch.position.x < (Screen.width/2)) 
            {
                MoveLeft(); //moves player left
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

JavaScript Code:

```
function Update()
{            
    for (var i = 0; i < Input.touchCount; i++) 
    {
        var touch : Touch = Input.GetTouch(i);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began) 
        {
            if (touch.position.x > (Screen.width/2)) 
            {
                MoveRight(); //moves player right
            }

            if (touch.position.x < (Screen.width/2)) 
            {
                MoveLeft(); //moves player left
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The main problem with such method is that player won't be able to have a control over how fast he moves left and right since everything is determined by a screen touch. So, normally, you would need to re-do alter game mechanics a bit to adapt to such changes.

In order to implement such feature, you'll have to get rid of Input.GetHorizontal() and Input.GetVertical() methods, as they'll always return 0 on mobile devices.
So, in your case, if you want to make your character move to the left, it could be something like this:

```
transform.Translate(speed*Time.deltaTime,0,0);
//replace 'MoveLeft()' with this line of code
```

This can be avoided by using an on-screen joystick, but they won't work well with users using small-screen touch devices. So, unless you're targeting tablet devices, you're in trouble.

This shouldn't conflict with your Desktop build, but if you want to ensure that the code would never run on anything other than mobile devices, you can make a use of [platform dependent compilation](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html) technique.

Hope this solves your underline problem!

Comment: Exactly,  I need to move the player left and right... could you please provide me by the implementation of these methods ?

Comment: I got  this error: Assets/firstStage/scripts/player_script.js(81,11): BCE0044: expecting ;, found 'i'.

Comment: is your code in java script or c# ?

Comment: It is not java script, I need it java script

Comment: I have updated my answer with Javascript code and explanation. I would strongly recommend learning C# for your future projects as it's more widely supported than Js when it comes to Unity scripting.